# How to get threshold from cumulative time series

Tags: r

In R, if I have a time series like so:

```
datetime          value
2014-12-01 00:00  100
2014-12-01 01:00  111
2014-12-01 02:00  98
2014-12-01 03:00  127
2014-12-01 04:00  114
2014-12-01 05:00  105
...
```

How can I get an interpolated datetime when the cumulative of this series reaches a certain value? Something like this:

```
somefunction(data, 250) // returns 2014-12-01 01:23
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your `datetime` is a nice `POSIXct` object, like this:

```
foo <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1417388400, 1417392000, 
1417395600, 1417399200, 1417402800, 1417406400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), value = c(100, 111, 98, 127, 114, 105
)), .Names = c("datetime", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
foo
             datetime value
1 2014-12-01 00:00:00   100
2 2014-12-01 01:00:00   111
3 2014-12-01 02:00:00    98
4 2014-12-01 03:00:00   127
5 2014-12-01 04:00:00   114
6 2014-12-01 05:00:00   105
```

And then, `approxfun` is your friend:

```
ff <- with(foo,approxfun(x=cumsum(value),y=datetime))
as.POSIXct(ff(250),origin=as.POSIXct("1970-01-01 01:00:00"))
[1] "2014-12-01 01:23:52 CET"
```

Comment: You need to ensure that the timezone of your result matches the timezone of the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `approx`:

```
Data <- structure(list(datetime = structure(c(1417413600, 1417417200, 
  1417420800, 1417424400, 1417428000, 1417431600), class = c("POSIXct", 
  "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), value = c(100L, 111L, 98L, 127L, 114L, 105L)),
  .Names = c("datetime", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -6L),
  class = "data.frame")
itime <- .POSIXct(approx(cumsum(Data$value), Data$datetime, 250)$y,
                  tz=attr(Data$datetime, "tzone"))
```